# Invalid format: not a PNG file

Tags: image, ubuntu, go, png

I have a code that downloads images from AWS S3, decodes them, and resizes them. The code supports images with PNG and JPG/JPEG formats.

Here is how I download the images from AWS S3:

```
//downloads an image from S3
func downloadImage(bucket string, item string) error {
file, err := os.Create(strings.Split(item, "/")[len(strings.Split(item, "/"))-1])
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Unable to open file", err)
    return err
}
//create a new AWS session
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("eu-west-1")},
)
//create the s3 downloader
downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

defer file.Close()
//download the image from S3
numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
    &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(item),
    })
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Unable to download item", item)
    fmt.Println(err)
    return err
}

fmt.Println("Downloaded", file.Name(), numBytes, "bytes")
return nil
}
```

Here is how I decode the images:

```
file, err := os.Open(image)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return err
}
if strings.Split(image, ".")[len(strings.Split(image, "."))-1] == "jpg" ||
    strings.Split(image, ".")[len(strings.Split(image, "."))-1] == "jpeg" {
    img, err := jpeg.Decode(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    file.Close()
}
else if strings.Split(image, ".")[len(strings.Split(image, "."))-1] == "png" {
    img, err := png.Decode(file)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    file.Close()
}
```

The images are downloaded, decoded, and resized successfully. A problem arises when the code downloads some PNG images (not all), and tries to decode them. It can't.

it generates the following error:

```
png: invalid format: not a PNG file
```

I am running everything on top of an Ubuntu 16.04. What is weird is that if I open this image using Image viewer, it generates the same error. However, if I open using any other program, such as: ImageMagick, the image opens without any complaint.

How can I overcome this issue in the Golang code?

Comment: Most likely it is a valid image, but not a PNG image. Use the general [`image.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode) function which detects the image type based on a registry. Don't forget to import `image/png`, `image/jpeg` and `image/gif` for it to recognize those formats (the imports will register the formats; use blank import if you don't use those packages).

Comment: Can you please explain the cause and the solution? It is a PNG image, since it has a PNG extension, and the Content-Type is PNG. Moreover, the image is successfully opened by some programs, namely imageMagick in ubuntu and photos in Windows, but not with image Viewer in Ubuntu

Comment: The format of an image is not defined by the extension of its name nor an associated content type. You can take a JPEG image and rename it to have a `.png` extension, that will not make it a PNG image, it will still be a JPEG image. The format of an image is defined by its content. Please report back if my suggestion solves your issue.

Comment: Check what the file actually is (name and content type are irrelevant) with `file`.

Comment: Post a zipped version of your file to protect it from being changed by this forum. Then others can check what the format actually is.

Comment: @icza you are right. I am posting an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Aparently, even though the extension name is .png, and its content type is PNG, it is not necessarily a PNG image. The only way to know for sure is by examining the image header.

One way to overcome this problem with GoLang is to use the general `image.Decode()` function which detects the image type based on a registry as suggested by @icza

Comment: The content-type used by the web server is derived from the file extension with most web servers (go's built in http server is actually an exception). On such web servers, it can only be as accurate as the file extension.